# Como abrir bytes de pdf em uma nova aba no navegador

Tags: c#, asp.net

Eu tenho os bytes do de um relatorio em pdf porém so achei como fazer o download.

```
    byte[] bytes = Relatorio.LocalReport.Render("PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);


        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.Clear();
        response.ContentType = "PDF";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "PDF"));
        response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        response.End();
```

Não quero fazer o download, quero que seja aberto em uma nova aba os bytes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não controla diretamente isso — eu, por exemplo, tenho o Firefox configurado pra baixar todos os .pdf automaticamente — mas você pode tentar colocar `inline` no lugar de `attachment`:

```
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("inline; filename={0}", "PDF"));
```

Pra abrir o documento numa **nova** aba, você pode colocar `target="_blank"` no link que acessa o PDF.

Comment: Resolvido! valeu.

Comment: target blank abre uma aba em branco